# Google Maps API Having Issues with Permissions After Gradle Migration

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having a small but weird issue with the Google Maps API. I recently switched from having my Gradle use Groovy to instead use Kotlin DSL. The migration was a success and everything works as intended, however I now get an error whenever I use the maps API that says:

> Missing permissions required by GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled: android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

The odd thing is that I did give permission for coarse and fine location. Again, everything compiles and works exactly as intended, with the user able to center the location on themselves, however this error still appears. Below is relevant code. Is this a known glitch with Kotlin DSL, or am I missing something?

Thank you.

[image: Issue I am seeing]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.groupupandroid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GroupUpAndroid"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

build.gradle.kts (app)

```
plugins {
    id ("com.android.application")
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id ("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin")
    id ("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.7.10"
}

android {
    compileSdk = 32

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.groupupandroid"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 32
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    val ktor_version = "2.0.3"
    val nav_version = "2.5.1"

    implementation ("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0")
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0")
    implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2")
    implementation ("com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1")
    implementation ("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation ("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3")
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0")

    // Kotlin
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")

    // Feature module Support
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version")

    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version")

    // Google Maps
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0")

    // Jetpack Compose Integration
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version")

    // Networking Plugins
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.4.0-RC")


    // Specifying kotlinx serialization
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version")

    //implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version")
    //implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    //implementation("com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:0.8.0")
}
```

build.gradle.kts (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        val nav_version = "2.5.0"
        classpath("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1")
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
        //classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.7.10")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "7.2.2" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "7.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.7.0" apply false
    id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin") version "2.0.1" apply false

}

tasks.register("clean",Delete::class){
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

Comment: Hey, did you get any solution for this? i have run into this issue recently. The application works fine though, so i just suppress it for now.